# Why doesn't this regex code work?

Tags: python, regex

```
line2 = '<div <a href="link" onmouseover="vli(this,7483989,1,4,5);"></div>'

matchObj = re.match( r'href="(.*?)"', line2)

if matchObj:
   print "matchObj.group() : ", matchObj.groups()
else:
   print "No match!!"
```

It outputs "No match!!". Shouldn't output be`['link']` ?

Answer (score 4):

You need to use `re.search` instead of `re.match`. `re.match` will only match at the beginning of the string.

From the [docs for `re.match`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.match):

> Note that even in MULTILINE mode, re.match() will only match at the
>   beginning of the string and not at the beginning of each line.
>
> If you want to locate a match anywhere in string, use search() instead
>   (see also search() vs. match()).